# Serialize an Object type member

Tags: android, object, serialization, uri

```
public class Data implements Serializable {
private String content;
private Object res;
private Uri uri;
}
```

How to make the class Serializable when there are Object and Uri members?

Comment: Arbitrary `Object` instances cannot be serialized. At minimum, declare `res` as being `Serializable`. You would have to handle `Uri` serialization yourself, converting to and from `String`.

Comment: To add to what CommonsWare said-  if the object res will always be a Serializable object, you can store is as a Serializable instead.  If it isn't, then this can't be done.

Comment: @CommonsWare, can you clarify what does "declare res as being Serializable" mean? 

I am storing image url path/image drawable in res alternately, so I had to make it `Object`.

Comment: @GabeSechan do you mean `private Serializable res;`?

Comment: "I am storing image url path/image drawable in res alternately" -- this is not a good idea.

Comment: @CommonsWare I need to share an image via `ACTION_SEND` which comes from two sources either URL or app resources. `res` keeps a reference accordingly.

Comment: Or, you could have two fields, each with the appropriate type.

Comment: @CommonsWare, any pitfalls to use `Serializable res;` as a safe solution?

Comment: You have the same pitfalls as using `Object`. One of Java's strengths is its type safety, and you are throwing that away for no obvious reason.

Comment: @CommonsWare That summarizes. Do you think having two types and checking which type has actual data is elegant?